# Rewriting Code in Internal Flash in STM32F439

Tags: microcontroller, stm32, flash, bootloader

I am using the [STM32F439](https://www.st.com/resource/en/datasheet/stm32f427vg.pdf) and looking to find a way to write code in the internal flash. Is there a protected area for quality assurance and security? It's supposed to be used for company's intellectual property.

I would also like to know if there's a way to rewrite the system memory, I presume that it is the most protected area and couldn't find a way to write the code on it.

Comment: By system memory, do you mean the internal factory bootloader? For your questions, which MCU documents you have read? The datasheet, reference manual and bootloader appnote?

Comment: Usually code in the internal flash is re-written with a JTAG tool like the st-link V2 or V3. If you want to modify code that is already there then you'll need the equivalent knowledge of a few computer engineering courses.

Comment: Your question is very unclear.  Maybe you'll be interested in the Read Protection (RDP) feature described in the Reference Manual.

Comment: "Im using the stm32f439 and looking to find a way to write code in the internal flash" This is utterly confusing. If you are "USING" it, than how you do it WITHOUT writing the code into internal flash?

Comment: Are you looking to get the chip to reprogram its own flash (ie, perform an in field firmware update), or are you looking for how to program during development/manufacture?

Answer (score 2):

Assuming the goal is protect company intellectual property, STM32F7 and STM32F401re  family of product offer distinct level of protection that might work.

**Readout Protection (RDP)**

- Level 0: No readout protection
- Level 1: memory readout protection
- Level 2: chip read out protection

**Proprietary code Read out Protection (PcROP)**

- PcROP is capable of preventing the CPU of executing malicious code

**Write Protection (WRP)**

- Protecting the flash sector Read/Write/Erase Access

The attached reference documents have in-depth details of the features. The following slide from the attached document might be of interest.

[image: Protect Confidentiality of Software]

Readout Protection Configuration are done through options bytes. Review the content around option bytes.

[image: Option Bytes]

The FLASH_OPTCR register is used to modify the option bytes.

In the respective microcontroller datasheet look for information similar to the below. This should help zero in the content that is of interest.

[image]

The system memory (ROM) stores the native bootloader (STM32F401re) and is read only.

**References:**

- [STM32 System Memory Protection](https://www.st.com/content/ccc/resource/training/technical/product_training/group0/f5/5e/87/93/f5/d7/45/85/STM32F7_Security_Memories_Protections/files/STM32F7_Security_Memories_Protections.pdf/jcr:content/translations/en.STM32F7_Security_Memories_Protections.pdf)
- [RM0090 Reference manual STM32F429/439 advanced Arm®-based 32-bit MCUs](https://www.st.com/resource/en/reference_manual/dm00031020-stm32f405-415-stm32f407-417-stm32f427-437-and-stm32f429-439-advanced-arm-based-32-bit-mcus-stmicroelectronics.pdf)